# Can i use selenium web driver for automation using c# in vs 2010?

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, automation

**can i use selenium web driver for automation  using c# in vs 2010**

- I am trying to automate set of process having fixed algorithm.
  For this i found selenium web driver as good option, but i want to
  implement it using c# not java.
- Can i use selenium web driver for automation using c# in visual studio 2010?
  If yes please specify the set process or sample example.
- Or is their any open source tool available, which will help to automate this   process better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Best way is to install Selenium Webdriver via the Nuget console in Visual Studio. You may need to follow these instructions to get Nuget working in VS 2010:

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/Using-Nuget-in-Visual-Studio-2010-&-2012

Once you have Nuget working you can install Selenium using the following link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver

This will install all the package files for you.

It might be worth reading a bit about Nuget first, it's very easy to use.